# 2 java processing hanging for about 2.8s

Tags: linux, centos, java, strace

I have 2 processes running on a VMWare server on the same vm. Centos 6.x

I ran strace on both processes and saved the output

```
6970  14:04:09.643295 futex(0x7f47d8027754, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f47d8027750, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1} <unfinished ...>
6969  14:04:09.643304 futex(0x7f47d8027754, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 54869, NULL <unfinished ...>
6971  14:04:09.643353 futex(0x7f47d802b128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
6970  14:04:09.643363 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.000063>
6969  14:04:09.643372 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 EAGAIN (Resource temporarily unavailable) <0.000063>
6971  14:04:09.643411 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.000052>
6969  14:04:09.643420 futex(0x7f47d8027728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1 <unfinished ...>
6971  14:04:09.643459 futex(0x7f47d8030854, FUTEX_WAKE_OP_PRIVATE, 1, 1, 0x7f47d8030850, {FUTEX_OP_SET, 0, FUTEX_OP_CMP_GT, 1} <unfinished ...>
6969  14:04:09.643469 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.000044>
6971  14:04:09.643501 <... futex resumed> ) = 1 <0.000037>
6974  14:04:09.650775 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.511421>
17035 14:04:12.446009 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.902876>
17009 14:04:12.446112 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=271, revents=POLLIN}]) <3.742208>
17008 14:04:12.446131 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=193, revents=POLLIN}]) <3.747483>
24085 14:04:12.446144 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.822784>
24082 14:04:12.446157 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=300, revents=POLLIN}]) <4.404341>
6416  14:04:12.446172 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=187, revents=POLLIN}]) <3.557929>
18296 14:04:12.446189 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.822459>
18295 14:04:12.446201 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=290, revents=POLLIN}]) <3.518658>
```

the key component is

```
6974  14:04:09.650775 <... futex resumed> ) = 0 <0.511421>
17035 14:04:12.446009 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.902876>
```

the other process strace is

```
7510  14:04:09.622601 futex(0x7f8874033728, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0 <0.000024>
7510  14:04:09.622698 getrusage(0x1 /* RUSAGE_??? */, {ru_utime={72, 763938}, ru_stime={3, 512466}, ...}) = 0 <0.000023>
7510  14:04:09.622761 futex(0x7f8874033754, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {162879, 332257449}, ffffffff <unfinished ...>
7543  14:04:09.644930 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <0.050089>
7543  14:04:09.644991 futex(0x7f88757c9128, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 1) = 0 <0.000039>
7543  14:04:09.645091 futex(0x7f88757c9154, FUTEX_WAIT_BITSET_PRIVATE, 1, {162879, 104576419}, ffffffff <unfinished ...>
7766  14:04:09.671201 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <0.100101>
17254 14:04:12.445858 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.859094>
24083 14:04:12.446056 <... poll resumed> ) = 1 ([\{fd=277, revents=POLLIN}]) <4.404263>
```

key bit is

```
7766  14:04:09.671201 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <0.100101>
17254 14:04:12.445858 <... futex resumed> ) = -1 ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out) <2.859094>
```

roughly the same time both java process stopped and them timed out.

Now I have other logs that show stuff happened in that time - I believe.

How can I track down what the futex was? Or how can I find more info / what more data can I grab to diagnose this issue?

Comment: Possibly a Linux kernel bug. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32262946/java-periodically-hangs-at-futex-and-very-low-io-output).

Comment: @xenoid This was 2015 - any kernel from that time would be very unsecure to run today (pre-spectre etc.).

Comment: I saw that kernel  bug but as point it out it's fairly old

Comment: I'm running latest centos 6.x